# colcon test errors

Tags: ros, ros2, colcon, ros-crystal

[image: Rosanswers logo]

After installing ROS 2 Crystal from debian packages on Ubuntu 18.04, I followed the [colcon tutorial](https://index.ros.org/doc/ros2/Tutorials/Colcon-Tutorial/) to build and test the sample ros2 packages.

I first created the ros2 workspace:

```
$ mkdir -p ~/ros2_ws/src
$ cd ~/ros2_ws
$ wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ros2/ros2/master/ros2.repos
$ vcs import ~/ros2_ws/src < ros2.repos
```

I then was able to build the packages successfully:

```
$ colcon build --symlink-install
Summary: 228 packages finished [1min 3s]
```

Despite the packages being built successfully, `colcon test` produces errors.

```
$ colcon test
Summary: 228 packages finished [28min 27s]
8 packages had stderr output: demo_nodes_cpp osrf_pycommon pendulum_control rcl rclcpp_action rqt test_cli tf2_ros
6 packages had test failures: demo_nodes_cpp pendulum_control rcl rclcpp_action test_cli tf2_ros
```

Running `colcon test` again produced different errors.

```
$ colcon test
Summary: 228 packages finished [27min 22s]
  11 packages had stderr output: composition demo_nodes_cpp image_tools osrf_pycommon pendulum_control rcl rclcpp_action rqt test_communication test_rclcpp tf2_ros
9 packages had test failures: composition demo_nodes_cpp image_tools pendulum_control rcl rclcpp_action test_communication test_rclcpp tf2_ros
```

I'm not sure what the issue could be, any insight would be really appreciated.

Edit: Adding errors produced by both `colcon test` attempts. Below are the snippets of the terminal outputs that are relevant to `stderr` outputs, or `test failure` outputs:

```
user@user-machine:~$ cd ros2_ws/
user@user-machine:~/ros2_ws$ colcon test

Starting >>> test_osrf_testing_tools_cpp
--- stderr: osrf_pycommon
test_remove_ansi_escape_senquences (tests.unit.test_terminal_color.test_ansi_re.TestTerminalColorAnsiRe) ... ok
test_remove_ansi_escape_senquences_false_positives (tests.unit.test_terminal_color.test_ansi_re.TestTerminalColorAnsiRe) ... ok
test_split_by_ansi_escape_sequence (tests.unit.test_terminal_color.test_ansi_re.TestTerminalColorAnsiRe) ... ok
test_ansi (tests.unit.test_terminal_color.test_impl.TestTerminalColorImpl) ... ok
test_enable_and_disable_ansi_color_substitution_globally (tests.unit.test_terminal_color.test_impl.TestTerminalColorImpl) ... ok
test_format_color (tests.unit.test_terminal_color.test_impl.TestTerminalColorImpl) ... ok
test_get_ansi_dict (tests.unit.test_terminal_color.test_impl.TestTerminalColorImpl) ... ok
test_sanitize (tests.unit.test_terminal_color.test_impl.TestTerminalColorImpl) ... ok
test_call_prepare_arguments (tests.unit.test_cli_utils.test_verb_pattern.TestCliUtilsVerbPattern) ... /home/user/ros2_ws/build/osrf_pycommon/osrf_pycommon/cli_utils/verb_pattern.py:44: DeprecationWarning: inspect.getargspec() is deprecated, use inspect.signature() or inspect.getfullargspec()
  arguments, _, _, defaults = inspect.getargspec(func)
/home/user/ros2_ws/src/osrf/osrf_pycommon/tests/unit/test_cli_utils/test_verb_pattern.py:69: DeprecationWarning: Please use assertRaisesRegex instead.
  with self.assertRaisesRegexp(ValueError, 'one or two parameters'):
/home/user/ros2_ws/build/osrf_pycommon/osrf_pycommon/cli_utils/verb_pattern.py:55: DeprecationWarning: inspect.getargspec() is deprecated, use inspect.signature() or inspect.getfullargspec()
  ', '.join(inspect.getargspec(func)[0])))
ok
test_split_arguments_by_verb (tests.unit.test_cli_utils.test_verb_pattern.TestCliUtilsVerbPattern) ... ok
test_is_tty (tests.unit.test_terminal_utils.TestTerminalUtils) ... ok
test_async_execute_process_no_emulation_shell_false (tests.unit.test_process_utils.test_async_execute_process.TestProcessUtilsAsyncExecuteProcess) ... /usr/lib/python3.6/asyncio/base_subprocess.py:131: ResourceWarning: unclosed transport <_UnixSubprocessTransport pid=1601 returncode=0 stdin=<_UnixWritePipeTransport closed fd=7 closed> stdout=<_UnixReadPipeTransport closed fd=8 closed> stderr=<_UnixReadPipeTransport closed fd=10 closed>>
  source=self)
ok
test_async_execute_process_no_emulation_shell_false_combined (tests.unit.test_process_utils.test_async_execute_process.TestProcessUtilsAsyncExecuteProcess) ... /usr/lib/python3.6/asyncio/base_subprocess.py:131: ResourceWarning: unclosed transport <_UnixSubprocessTransport pid=1610 returncode=0 stdin=<_UnixWritePipeTransport closed fd=7 closed> stdout=<_UnixReadPipeTransport closed fd=8 closed>>
  source=self)
ok
test_async_execute_process_no_emulation_shell_true (tests.unit.test_process_utils.test_async_execute_process.TestProcessUtilsAsyncExecuteProcess) ... /usr/lib/python3.6/asyncio/base_subprocess.py:131: ResourceWarning: unclosed transport <_UnixSubprocessTransport pid=1611 returncode=0 stdin=<_UnixWritePipeTransport closed fd=7 closed> stdout=<_UnixReadPipeTransport closed fd=8 closed> stderr=<_UnixReadPipeTransport closed fd=10 closed>>
  source=self)
ok
test_async_execute_process_no_emulation_shell_true_combined (tests.unit.test_process_utils.test_async_execute_process.TestProcessUtilsAsyncExecuteProcess) ... /usr/lib/python3.6/asyncio/base_subprocess.py:131: ResourceWarning: unclosed transport <_UnixSubprocessTransport pid=1613 returncode=0 stdin=<_UnixWritePipeTransport closed fd=7 closed> stdout=<_UnixReadPipeTransport closed fd=8 closed>>
  source=self)
ok
test_async_execute_process_with_emulation_shell_false (tests.unit.test_process_utils.test_async_execute_process.TestProcessUtilsAsyncExecuteProcess) ... ok
test_async_execute_process_with_emulation_shell_false_combined (tests.unit.test_process_utils.test_async_execute_process.TestProcessUtilsAsyncExecuteProcess) ... ok
test_async_execute_process_with_emulation_shell_true (tests.unit.test_process_utils.test_async_execute_process.TestProcessUtilsAsyncExecuteProcess) ... /usr/lib/python3.6/asyncio/base_subprocess.py:131: ResourceWarning: unclosed transport <_UnixSubprocessTransport pid=1616 returncode=0 stdin=<_UnixWritePipeTransport closed fd=11 closed>>
  source=self)
/usr/lib/python3.6/asyncio/base_subprocess.py:131: ResourceWarning: unclosed transport <_UnixSubprocessTransport pid=1617 returncode=0 stdin=<_UnixWritePipeTransport closed fd=9 closed>>
  source=self)
ok
test_async_execute_process_with_emulation_shell_true_combined (tests.unit.test_process_utils.test_async_execute_process.TestProcessUtilsAsyncExecuteProcess) ... ok
test_which (tests.unit.test_process_utils.test_impl.TestProcessUtilsImpl) ... ok
test__execute_process_pty (tests.unit.test_process_utils.test_execute_process_pty.TestProcessUtilsExecuteNoPty) ... ok
test__execute_process_pty_combined (tests.unit.test_process_utils.test_execute_process_pty.TestProcessUtilsExecuteNoPty) ... ok
test__execute_process_pty_combined_unbuffered (tests.unit.test_process_utils.test_execute_process_pty.TestProcessUtilsExecuteNoPty) ... ok
test__execute_process_pty_unbuffered (tests.unit.test_process_utils.test_execute_process_pty.TestProcessUtilsExecuteNoPty) ... ok
test__execute_process_nopty (tests.unit.test_process_utils.test_execute_process_nopty.TestProcessUtilsExecuteNoPty) ... /home/user/ros2_ws/src/osrf/osrf_pycommon/tests/unit/test_process_utils/test_execute_process_nopty.py:127: ResourceWarning: unclosed file <_io.BufferedWriter name=13>
  break
/home/user/ros2_ws/src/osrf/osrf_pycommon/tests/unit/test_process_utils/test_execute_process_nopty.py:127: ResourceWarning: unclosed file <_io.BufferedReader name=14>
  break
/home/user/ros2_ws/src/osrf/osrf_pycommon/tests/unit/test_process_utils/test_execute_process_nopty.py:127: ResourceWarning: unclosed file <_io.BufferedReader name=16>
  break
ok
test__execute_process_nopty_combined (tests.unit.test_process_utils.test_execute_process_nopty.TestProcessUtilsExecuteNoPty) ... /home/user/ros2_ws/src/osrf/osrf_pycommon/tests/unit/test_process_utils/test_execute_process_nopty.py:104: ResourceWarning: unclosed file <_io.BufferedWriter name=13>
  break
/home/user/ros2_ws/src/osrf/osrf_pycommon/tests/unit/test_process_utils/test_execute_process_nopty.py:104: ResourceWarning: unclosed file <_io.BufferedReader name=14>
  break
ok
test__execute_process_nopty_combined_unbuffered (tests.unit.test_process_utils.test_execute_process_nopty.TestProcessUtilsExecuteNoPty) ... /home/user/ros2_ws/src/osrf/osrf_pycommon/tests/unit/test_process_utils/test_execute_process_nopty.py:58: ResourceWarning: unclosed file <_io.BufferedWriter name=13>
  break
/home/user/ros2_ws/src/osrf/osrf_pycommon/tests/unit/test_process_utils/test_execute_process_nopty.py:58: ResourceWarning: unclosed file <_io.BufferedReader name=14>
  break
ok
test__execute_process_nopty_unbuffered (tests.unit.test_process_utils.test_execute_process_nopty.TestProcessUtilsExecuteNoPty) ... /home/user/ros2_ws/src/osrf/osrf_pycommon/tests/unit/test_process_utils/test_execute_process_nopty.py:81: ResourceWarning: unclosed file <_io.BufferedWriter name=13>
  break
/home/user/ros2_ws/src/osrf/osrf_pycommon/tests/unit/test_process_utils/test_execute_process_nopty.py:81: ResourceWarning: unclosed file <_io.BufferedReader name=14>
  break
/home/user/ros2_ws/src/osrf/osrf_pycommon/tests/unit/test_process_utils/test_execute_process_nopty.py:81: ResourceWarning: unclosed file <_io.BufferedReader name=16>
  break
ok
test__process_incomming_lines (tests.unit.test_process_utils.test_execute_process_nopty.TestProcessUtilsExecuteNoPty) ... ok

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 29 tests in 0.883s

OK
---
Finished <<< osrf_pycommon [3.38s]
Finished <<< test_osrf_testing_tools_cpp [0.80s]              

[Processing: rcl]                                 
--- stderr: rcl                                   
Errors while running CTest
---
Finished <<< rcl [2min 38s] [ with test failures ]

Starting >>> rqt_publisher
--- stderr: rqt                                                                                                                                                                                       

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 0 tests in 0.000s

OK
---
Finished <<< rqt [1.35s]

Starting >>> pendulum_control
--- stderr: tf2_ros                                                                                                                                                                                             
Errors while running CTest
---
Finished <<< tf2_ros [1min 1s]  [ with test failures ]
Starting >>> tf2_geometry_msgs
--- stderr: rclcpp_action                                                                                                                                                                                           
Errors while running CTest
---
Finished <<< rclcpp_action [1min 10s]   [ with test failures ]

Starting >>> ros2lifecycle
--- stderr: demo_nodes_cpp                                                                                                                                                                        
Errors while running CTest
---
Finished <<< demo_nodes_cpp [1min 11s]  [ with test failures ]

--- stderr: pendulum_control                                                                                                                                                                    
Errors while running CTest
---

Starting >>> rviz_visual_testing_framework
--- stderr: test_cli                                                                                                                                                                  
Errors while running CTest
---
Finished <<< test_cli [1min 6s] [ with test failures ]

Summary: 228 packages finished [28min 27s]
  8 packages had stderr output: demo_nodes_cpp osrf_pycommon pendulum_control rcl rclcpp_action rqt test_cli tf2_ros
  6 packages had test failures: demo_nodes_cpp pendulum_control rcl rclcpp_action test_cli tf2_ros
user@user-machine:~/ros2_ws$ colcon test 

Starting >>> console_bridge_vendor
--- stderr: osrf_pycommon                                                                                                                                                                     
test_remove_ansi_escape_senquences (tests.unit.test_terminal_color.test_ansi_re.TestTerminalColorAnsiRe) ... ok
test_remove_ansi_escape_senquences_false_positives (tests.unit.test_terminal_color.test_ansi_re.TestTerminalColorAnsiRe) ... ok
test_split_by_ansi_escape_sequence (tests.unit.test_terminal_color.test_ansi_re.TestTerminalColorAnsiRe) ... ok
test_ansi (tests.unit.test_terminal_color.test_impl.TestTerminalColorImpl) ... ok
test_enable_and_disable_ansi_color_substitution_globally (tests.unit.test_terminal_color.test_impl.TestTerminalColorImpl) ... ok
test_format_color (tests.unit.test_terminal_color.test_impl.TestTerminalColorImpl) ... ok
test_get_ansi_dict (tests.unit.test_terminal_color.test_impl.TestTerminalColorImpl) ... ok
test_sanitize (tests.unit.test_terminal_color.test_impl.TestTerminalColorImpl) ... ok
test_call_prepare_arguments (tests.unit.test_cli_utils.test_verb_pattern.TestCliUtilsVerbPattern) ... /home/user/ros2_ws/build/osrf_pycommon/osrf_pycommon/cli_utils/verb_pattern.py:44: DeprecationWarning: inspect.getargspec() is deprecated, use inspect.signature() or inspect.getfullargspec()
  arguments, _, _, defaults = inspect.getargspec(func)
/home/user/ros2_ws/src/osrf/osrf_pycommon/tests/unit/test_cli_utils/test_verb_pattern.py:69: DeprecationWarning: Please use assertRaisesRegex instead.
  with self.assertRaisesRegexp(ValueError, 'one or two parameters'):
/home/user/ros2_ws/build/osrf_pycommon/osrf_pycommon/cli_utils/verb_pattern.py:55: DeprecationWarning: inspect.getargspec() is deprecated, use inspect.signature() or inspect.getfullargspec()
  ', '.join(inspect.getargspec(func)[0])))
ok
test_split_arguments_by_verb (tests.unit.test_cli_utils.test_verb_pattern.TestCliUtilsVerbPattern) ... ok
test_is_tty (tests.unit.test_terminal_utils.TestTerminalUtils) ... ok
test_async_execute_process_no_emulation_shell_false (tests.unit.test_process_utils.test_async_execute_process.TestProcessUtilsAsyncExecuteProcess) ... /usr/lib/python3.6/asyncio/base_subprocess.py:131: ResourceWarning: unclosed transport <_UnixSubprocessTransport pid=5551 returncode=0 stdin=<_UnixWritePipeTransport closed fd=7 closed> stdout=<_UnixReadPipeTransport closed fd=8 closed> stderr=<_UnixReadPipeTransport closed fd=10 closed>>
  source=self)
ok
test_async_execute_process_no_emulation_shell_false_combined (tests.unit.test_process_utils.test_async_execute_process.TestProcessUtilsAsyncExecuteProcess) ... /usr/lib/python3.6/asyncio/base_subprocess.py:131: ResourceWarning: unclosed transport <_UnixSubprocessTransport pid=5555 returncode=0 stdin=<_UnixWritePipeTransport closed fd=7 closed> stdout=<_UnixReadPipeTransport closed fd=8 closed>>
  source=self)
ok
test_async_execute_process_no_emulation_shell_true (tests.unit.test_process_utils.test_async_execute_process.TestProcessUtilsAsyncExecuteProcess) ... /usr/lib/python3.6/asyncio/base_subprocess.py:131: ResourceWarning: unclosed transport <_UnixSubprocessTransport pid=5556 returncode=0 stdin=<_UnixWritePipeTransport closed fd=7 closed> stdout=<_UnixReadPipeTransport closed fd=8 closed> stderr=<_UnixReadPipeTransport closed fd=10 closed>>
  source=self)
ok
test_async_execute_process_no_emulation_shell_true_combined (tests.unit.test_process_utils.test_async_execute_process.TestProcessUtilsAsyncExecuteProcess) ... /usr/lib/python3.6/asyncio/base_subprocess.py:131: ResourceWarning: unclosed transport <_UnixSubprocessTransport pid=5558 returncode=0 stdin=<_UnixWritePipeTransport closed fd=7 closed> stdout=<_UnixReadPipeTransport closed fd=8 closed>>
  source=self)
ok
test_async_execute_process_with_emulation_shell_false (tests.unit.test_process_utils.test_async_execute_process.TestProcessUtilsAsyncExecuteProcess) ... ok
test_async_execute_process_with_emulation_shell_false_combined (tests.unit.test_process_utils.test_async_execute_process.TestProcessUtilsAsyncExecuteProcess) ... ok
test_async_execute_process_with_emulation_shell_true (tests.unit.test_process_utils.test_async_execute_process.TestProcessUtilsAsyncExecuteProcess) ... ok
test_async_execute_process_with_emulation_shell_true_combined (tests.unit.test_process_utils.test_async_execute_process.TestProcessUtilsAsyncExecuteProcess) ... /usr/lib/python3.6/asyncio/base_subprocess.py:131: ResourceWarning: unclosed transport <_UnixSubprocessTransport pid=5571 returncode=0 stdin=<_UnixWritePipeTransport closed fd=11 closed>>
  source=self)
/usr/lib/python3.6/asyncio/base_subprocess.py:131: ResourceWarning: unclosed transport <_UnixSubprocessTransport pid=5572 returncode=0 stdin=<_UnixWritePipeTransport closed fd=9 closed>>
  source=self)
/usr/lib/python3.6/asyncio/base_subprocess.py:131: ResourceWarning: unclosed transport <_UnixSubprocessTransport pid=5575 returncode=0 stdin=<_UnixWritePipeTransport closed fd=11 closed>>
  source=self)
ok
test_which (tests.unit.test_process_utils.test_impl.TestProcessUtilsImpl) ... ok
test__execute_process_pty (tests.unit.test_process_utils.test_execute_process_pty.TestProcessUtilsExecuteNoPty) ... ok
test__execute_process_pty_combined (tests.unit.test_process_utils.test_execute_process_pty.TestProcessUtilsExecuteNoPty) ... ok
test__execute_process_pty_combined_unbuffered (tests.unit.test_process_utils.test_execute_process_pty.TestProcessUtilsExecuteNoPty) ... ok
test__execute_process_pty_unbuffered (tests.unit.test_process_utils.test_execute_process_pty.TestProcessUtilsExecuteNoPty) ... ok
test__execute_process_nopty (tests.unit.test_process_utils.test_execute_process_nopty.TestProcessUtilsExecuteNoPty) ... /home/user/ros2_ws/src/osrf/osrf_pycommon/tests/unit/test_process_utils/test_execute_process_nopty.py:127: ResourceWarning: unclosed file <_io.BufferedWriter name=13>
  break
/home/user/ros2_ws/src/osrf/osrf_pycommon/tests/unit/test_process_utils/test_execute_process_nopty.py:127: ResourceWarning: unclosed file <_io.BufferedReader name=14>
  break
/home/user/ros2_ws/src/osrf/osrf_pycommon/tests/unit/test_process_utils/test_execute_process_nopty.py:127: ResourceWarning: unclosed file <_io.BufferedReader name=16>
  break
ok
test__execute_process_nopty_combined (tests.unit.test_process_utils.test_execute_process_nopty.TestProcessUtilsExecuteNoPty) ... /home/user/ros2_ws/src/osrf/osrf_pycommon/tests/unit/test_process_utils/test_execute_process_nopty.py:104: ResourceWarning: unclosed file <_io.BufferedWriter name=13>
  break
/home/user/ros2_ws/src/osrf/osrf_pycommon/tests/unit/test_process_utils/test_execute_process_nopty.py:104: ResourceWarning: unclosed file <_io.BufferedReader name=14>
  break
ok
test__execute_process_nopty_combined_unbuffered (tests.unit.test_process_utils.test_execute_process_nopty.TestProcessUtilsExecuteNoPty) ... /home/user/ros2_ws/src/osrf/osrf_pycommon/tests/unit/test_process_utils/test_execute_process_nopty.py:58: ResourceWarning: unclosed file <_io.BufferedWriter name=13>
  break
/home/user/ros2_ws/src/osrf/osrf_pycommon/tests/unit/test_process_utils/test_execute_process_nopty.py:58: ResourceWarning: unclosed file <_io.BufferedReader name=14>
  break
ok
test__execute_process_nopty_unbuffered (tests.unit.test_process_utils.test_execute_process_nopty.TestProcessUtilsExecuteNoPty) ... /home/user/ros2_ws/src/osrf/osrf_pycommon/tests/unit/test_process_utils/test_execute_process_nopty.py:81: ResourceWarning: unclosed file <_io.BufferedWriter name=13>
  break
/home/user/ros2_ws/src/osrf/osrf_pycommon/tests/unit/test_process_utils/test_execute_process_nopty.py:81: ResourceWarning: unclosed file <_io.BufferedReader name=14>
  break
/home/user/ros2_ws/src/osrf/osrf_pycommon/tests/unit/test_process_utils/test_execute_process_nopty.py:81: ResourceWarning: unclosed file <_io.BufferedReader name=16>
  break
ok
test__process_incomming_lines (tests.unit.test_process_utils.test_execute_process_nopty.TestProcessUtilsExecuteNoPty) ... ok

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 29 tests in 0.540s

OK
---
Finished <<< osrf_pycommon [2.71s]
                                           
[Processing: rcl]                                 
--- stderr: rcl                                   
Errors while running CTest
---
Finished <<< rcl [2min 35s] [ with test failures ]
                                                                                                                                                                 
Starting >>> rqt
--- stderr: rqt                                                                                                                                                                                                     

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 0 tests in 0.000s

OK
---
                                                                                                                                                                                
Starting >>> lifecycle
--- stderr: tf2_ros                                                                                                                                                                                                
Errors while running CTest
---
Finished <<< tf2_ros [1min 0s]  [ with test failures ]
Starting >>> tf2_geometry_msgs
--- stderr: image_tools
Errors while running CTest
---
Finished <<< image_tools [48.2s]    [ with test failures ]

Starting >>> tf2_eigen
--- stderr: rclcpp_action                                                                                                                                                                                 
Errors while running CTest
---
Finished <<< rclcpp_action [1min 9s]    [ with test failures ]

Starting >>> rviz_visual_testing_framework
--- stderr: pendulum_control
Errors while running CTest
---
Finished <<< pendulum_control [14.3s]   [ with test failures ]
Starting >>> rviz_default_plugins
--- stderr: demo_nodes_cpp                                                                                                                                                           
Errors while running CTest
---
Finished <<< demo_nodes_cpp [1min 28s]  [ with test failures ]
Starting >>> rviz2
Finished <<< rviz2 [1.87s]                                                                                                                   
--- stderr: composition                                                                                                            
Errors while running CTest
---
Finished <<< composition [2min 27s] [ with test failures ]
Starting >>> ros1_bridge
Finished <<< ros1_bridge [0.31s]                                                                                             
[Processing: test_communication, test_rclcpp]                                                            
[Processing: test_communication, test_rclcpp]                                                            
[Processing: test_communication, test_rclcpp]                                                            
--- stderr: test_rclcpp                                                                                  
Errors while running CTest
---
Finished <<< test_rclcpp [3min 20s] [ with test failures ]
[Processing: test_communication]                                  
[Processing: test_communication]                                  
[Processing: test_communication]                                  
[Processing: test_communication]                                  
[Processing: test_communication]                                  
[Processing: test_communication]                                  
[Processing: test_communication]                                  
[Processing: test_communication]                                  
[Processing: test_communication]                                  
[Processing: test_communication]                                  
[Processing: test_communication]                                  
[Processing: test_communication]                                  
[Processing: test_communication]                                  
[Processing: test_communication]                                  
[Processing: test_communication]                                   
[Processing: test_communication]                                   
[Processing: test_communication]                                   
[Processing: test_communication]                                   
[Processing: test_communication]                                   
[Processing: test_communication]                                   
[Processing: test_communication]                                   
[Processing: test_communication]                                   
[Processing: test_communication]                                   
[Processing: test_communication]                                   
[Processing: test_communication]                                   
[Processing: test_communication]                                   
[Processing: test_communication]                                   
[Processing: test_communication]                                   
[Processing: test_communication]                                   
[Processing: test_communication]                                   
[Processing: test_communication]                                   
--- stderr: test_communication                                     
Errors while running CTest
---
Finished <<< test_communication [18min 47s] [ with test failures ]

Summary: 228 packages finished [27min 22s]
  11 packages had stderr output: composition demo_nodes_cpp image_tools osrf_pycommon pendulum_control rcl rclcpp_action rqt test_communication test_rclcpp tf2_ros
  9 packages had test failures: composition demo_nodes_cpp image_tools pendulum_control rcl rclcpp_action test_communication test_rclcpp tf2_ros
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/313713/colcon-test-errors/) by [jdcarp](https://answers.ros.org/users/26475/jdcarp/) on ROS Answers with karma: 18 on 2019-01-24

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) on 2019-01-24**:
You would need to share the actual `stderr` output as well as details about the test failures in order to give you specific feedback.

**Comment by [jdcarp](https://answers.ros.org/users/26475/jdcarp/) on 2019-01-24**:
Thank you for your reply! I've added the relevant terminal outputs in an edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

First of all you are not building Crystal but the current source code from the master branch. You are not using the Crystal Debian packages you installed before. Either or would be sufficient - you don't have to do both.

Some packages do output something on `stderr` during running the tests (e.g. `osrf_pycommon`). Others are printing `Errors while running CTest` in case any tests fail. From the output it is still not clear though which tests failed.

You can also compare your results with the latest nightly builds and their results: https://ci.ros2.org/view/nightly/

---

Originally posted by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) with karma: 16276 on 2019-01-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jdcarp](https://answers.ros.org/users/26475/jdcarp/) on 2019-01-25**:
Thank you, sorry for the confusion!